# What are the PC controls for Chop?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

What are the default controls for Chop on the PC? As in, how to take him for a walk, etc.

I found [two](http://www.gta5cheats.com/list-commands-control-chop/) [sites](http://orcz.com/GTA_V:_Chop_Commands) that list the controls for consoles, but I can't figure out the controls on PC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you must have been progressed the story to a certain degree.

It usually shows the controls in the top left corner. For me it was (I suppose you must be unarmed):

> Hold <kbd>Right Mouse</kbd> to activate the further Chop-menu.

Here is the menu I got while holding the <kbd>Right Mouse</kbd> button. Notice, that there is no option for playing fetch. I suppose this depends on the environment you're in and if you have picked up a toy or not.

[image]

I suppose you know this but just for completeness:
**Make sure you're playing as character "Franklin".**